# Redirect any url if url not contain .php string

Tags: regex, nginx

Please help me, I want to redirect any url if url not contain ".php" string to no#3 format

I have tried like this but still got error:

```
rewrite ^(.*)\/(?!.*php)(.*)$ $1/cat/$3 redirect;
```

Example

```
1 https://example.com/abc/
2 https://example.com/abc.php
3 https://example.com/cat/abc
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7rWR.png)

Your answer is really appreciated.

Comment: see: [serverfault.com: Redirect of all the URLs that contain 1 word in specific, but that do not contain other words](https://serverfault.com/questions/837598/redirect-of-all-the-urls-that-contain-1-word-in-specific-but-that-do-not-contai), and use the word `.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern does not contain 3 capture groups but 2, so you should not be using `$3` in the replacement.

Depending on the format of the url that you want to rewrite:

```
^(https?://(?!\S*\.php\b)\S*)/([^\s/]*)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `https?://` Match the protocol
  - `(?!\S*\.php\b)` Assert that the string does not contain `.php`
  - `\S*` Match optional non whitespace characters
- `)` Close group 1
- `/` Match `/`
- `([^\s/]*)` Capture **group 2**, match optional non whitespace characters except `/`
- `$` End of string

In the replacement use `$1/cat/$2`

Note that with the replacement, if `/cat` is already present in the string, the replacement can also give you `/cat/cat`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i7efPQ/1)

Comment: how to prevent become /cat/cat if /cat already present?

Comment: @fitra68 Like this? `^(https?://(?!\S*\.php\b)\S*)/(?!cat$)(?<!/cat/)([^\s/]*)$` https://regex101.com/r/kkkEIs/1